# What output does apt.exe produce?

Tags: java, annotations

I'm a junior C++ developer that has only recently started learning Java and am looking at Annotations.  I see reference to apt.exe as an annotations processor.  In general I understand what this means, but I'm unable to find an explanation of what apt.exe actually does in plain english.

I've found this: "The apt tool is a command-line utility for annotation processing. It includes a set of reflective APIs and supporting infrastructure to process program annotations (JSR 175). These reflective APIs provide a build-time, source-based, read-only view of program structure. They are designed to cleanly model the Java programming language's type system after the addition of generics (JSR 14)."

Is this saying that is provides an overview of the program structure using annotations and reflective processing?  Something along the lines of [understand-c/understand-c++](https://scitools.com)?  Or is it simply compiling all the available documentation of the program as detailed by the Annotations?

The most confusing thing to me is that my coursework states that apt.exe continually calls annotation processors it finds to "…generate source files" and does so until the available annotation processors "…fail to generate new source files".  I don't understand what these source files are for that it is referencing.

Comment: "Note: The apt tool and its associated API contaiined in the pakcage com.sun.mirror have been deprecated since Java SE 7. Use the options available in the javac tool and the APIs contained in the packages javax.annotation.processing and javax.lang.model to process annotations." -- from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/apt/

Comment: Yes, I came across this, but there are projects I'm getting involved with that still use Java SE 6, so I wanted to understand this statement about generated source files better.